# Getting a CSS/JS popup in front of embedded Youtube video

Tags: video, background, youtube, popup, embed

I have a popup for my site notice. The popup darkens the background and is in front of everything else. Only an embedded Youtube video is still in front of the popup, I guess because it is Flash. In Firefox the Video is "almost" in the background, it just cuts some corners of the popup, in IE the complete popup hides behind the Video. I already tried to give the Video a lower z-index, but it won't work.

```
#light{
    z-index:1001;
    font-size: 10px;
}

#video{
    margin: 20px 0px 0px 0px;
    z-index:998;
}

<ul>
    <li>
        <iframe id="video" width="500" height="282" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/F4Z4-KCJ664" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

Replace the iframe line with the code below

```
<iframe id="video" width="500" height="282" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/F4Z4-KCJ664?wmode=transparent" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

and also give position:relative to both css blocks #light and #video

Comment: You sir, are a genius!
I just thought about a workaround like that:
function lightbox_open(){
 document.getElementById('video').style.display='none';
}
but unfortunately this would destroy the website while the popup is opened. Your suggestion works fine, thank you.